# 500 Internal Server Error for a jquery/ajax CALL (POST method)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, prestashop

I'm on Prestashop 1.6 and I've been experiencing a new bug since 2 days now.

I have a homemade module that let me to generate a zip file...

Everything was working fine until 2 days ago.

When I try to generate the zip file, nothing happens.

When I open the chrome console, here is what I find :

```
Remote Address:104.28.1.153:80
Request URL:http://xxxxxxx.tn/shop/admin1385/ajax-tab.php
Request Method:POST
Status Code:500 Internal Server Error
```

And here is my server log

```
[Wed Dec 02 22:55:48 2015] [error] [client 141.101.92.219] SoftException in Application.cpp:256: File "/home/picstore/public_html/shop/admin1385/ajax-tab.php" is writeable by group, referer: http://picstore.tn/shop/admin1385/index.php?controller=AdminLogin&token=14abda336e05072c8006141dc4ec23d2&redirect=AdminDashboard
[Wed Dec 02 22:55:03 2015] [error] [client 141.101.92.219] File does not exist: /home/picstore/public_html/500.shtml, referer: http://picstore.tn/shop/admin1385/index.php?controller=AdminLogin&token=14abda336e05072c8006141dc4ec23d2&redirect=AdminDashboard
[Wed Dec 02 22:55:03 2015] [error] [client 141.101.92.219] SoftException in Application.cpp:256: File "/home/picstore/public_html/shop/admin1385/ajax-tab.php" is writeable by group, referer: http://picstore.tn/shop/admin1385/index.php?controller=AdminLogin&token=14abda336e05072c8006141dc4ec23d2&redirect=AdminDashboard
[Wed Dec 02 22:54:48 2015] [error] [client 141.101.92.219] File does not exist: /home/picstore/public_html/500.shtml, referer: http://picstore.tn/shop/admin1385/index.php?controller=AdminLogin&token=14abda336e05072c8006141dc4ec23d2&redirect=AdminDashboard
[Wed Dec 02 22:54:48 2015] [error] [client 141.101.92.219] SoftException in Application.cpp:256: File "/home/picstore/public_html/shop/admin1385/ajax-tab.php" is writeable by group, referer: http://picstore.tn/shop/admin1385/index.php?controller=AdminLogin&token=14abda336e05072c8006141dc4ec23d2&redirect=AdminDashboard
[Wed Dec 02 22:53:43 2015] [error] [client 141.101.92.219] File does not exist: /home/picstore/public_html/500.shtml, referer: http://picstore.tn/shop/admin1385/index.php?controller=AdminLogin&token=14abda336e05072c8006141dc4ec23d2&redirect=AdminDashboard
[Wed Dec 02 22:53:43 2015] [error] [client 141.101.92.219] SoftException in Application.cpp:256: File "/home/picstore/public_html/shop/admin1385/ajax-tab.php" is writeable by group, referer: http://picstore.tn/shop/admin1385/index.php?controller=AdminLogin&token=14abda336e05072c8006141dc4ec23d2&redirect=AdminDashboard
[Wed Dec 02 22:47:45 2015] [error] [client 141.101.92.219] File does not exist: /home/picstore/public_html/500.shtml, referer: http://picstore.tn/shop/admin1385/index.php?controller=AdminLogin&token=14abda336e05072c8006141dc4ec23d2&redirect=AdminDashboard
[Wed Dec 02 22:47:45 2015] [error] [client 141.101.92.219] SoftException in Application.cpp:256: File "/home/picstore/public_html/shop/admin1385/ajax-tab.php" is writeable by group, referer: http://picstore.tn/shop/admin1385/index.php?controller=AdminLogin&token=14abda336e05072c8006141dc4ec23d2&redirect=AdminDashboard
[Wed Dec 02 22:46:25 2015] [error] [client 141.101.92.210] File does not exist: /home/picstore/public_html/500.shtml, referer: https://www.picstore.tn/shop/admin1385/index.php?controller=AdminLogin&token=14abda336e05072c8006141dc4ec23d2
[Wed Dec 02 22:46:25 2015] [error] [client 141.101.92.210] SoftException in Application.cpp:256: File "/home/picstore/public_html/shop/admin1385/ajax-tab.php" is writeable by group, referer: https://www.picstore.tn/shop/admin1385/index.php?controller=AdminLogin&token=14abda336e05072c8006141dc4ec23d2
[Wed Dec 02 22:46:16 2015] [error] [client 141.101.92.210] File does not exist: /home/picstore/public_html/500.shtml, referer: https://www.picstore.tn/shop/admin1385/index.php?controller=AdminLogin&token=14abda336e05072c8006141dc4ec23d2&redirect=AdminDashboard
[Wed Dec 02 22:46:16 2015] [error] [client 141.101.92.210] SoftException in Application.cpp:256: File "/home/picstore/public_html/shop/admin1385/ajax-tab.php" is writeable by group, referer: https://www.picstore.tn/shop/admin1385/index.php?controller=AdminLogin&token=14abda336e05072c8006141dc4ec23d2&redirect=AdminDashboard
[Wed Dec 02 22:46:04 2015] [error] [client 141.101.92.219] File does not exist: /home/picstore/public_html/500.shtml, referer: https://picstore.tn/shop/admin1385/index.php?controller=AdminLogin&token=14abda336e05072c8006141dc4ec23d2&redirect=AdminDashboard
[Wed Dec 02 22:46:04 2015] [error] [client 141.101.92.219] SoftException in Application.cpp:256: File "/home/picstore/public_html/shop/admin1385/ajax-tab.php" is writeable by group, referer: https://picstore.tn/shop/admin1385/index.php?controller=AdminLogin&token=14abda336e05072c8006141dc4ec23d2&redirect=AdminDashboard
[Wed Dec 02 22:45:58 2015] [error] [client 141.101.92.219] File does not exist: /home/picstore/public_html/500.shtml, referer: http://picstore.tn/shop/admin1385/index.php?controller=AdminLogin&token=14abda336e05072c8006141dc4ec23d2&redirect=AdminDashboard
[Wed Dec 02 22:45:58 2015] [error] [client 141.101.92.219] SoftException in Application.cpp:256: File "/home/picstore/public_html/shop/admin1385/ajax-tab.php" is writeable by group, referer: http://picstore.tn/shop/admin1385/index.php?controller=AdminLogin&token=14abda336e05072c8006141dc4ec23d2&redirect=AdminDashboard
[Wed Dec 02 22:45:21 2015] [error] [client 141.101.92.219] File does not exist: /home/picstore/public_html/500.shtml, referer: http://picstore.tn/shop/admin1385/index.php?controller=AdminLogin&token=14abda336e05072c8006141dc4ec23d2&redirect=AdminDashboard
[Wed Dec 02 22:45:21 2015] [error] [client 141.101.92.219] SoftException in Application.cpp:256: File "/home/picstore/public_html/shop/admin1385/ajax-tab.php" is writeable by group, referer: http://picstore.tn/shop/admin1385/index.php?controller=AdminLogin&token=14abda336e05072c8006141dc4ec23d2&redirect=AdminDashboard
[Wed Dec 02 22:45:09 2015] [error] [client 141.101.92.210] File does not exist: /home/picstore/public_html/404.shtml, referer: https://www.picstore.tn/shop/
[Wed Dec 02 22:45:09 2015] [error] [client 141.101.92.210] File does not exist: /home/picstore/public_html/shop/10-le-poster.html, referer: https://www.picstore.tn/shop/
[Wed Dec 02 22:43:08 2015] [error] [client 141.101.92.219] File does not exist: /home/picstore/public_html/500.shtml, referer: http://picstore.tn/shop/admin1385/index.php?controller=AdminLogin&token=14abda336e05072c8006141dc4ec23d2&redirect=AdminDashboard
[Wed Dec 02 22:43:08 2015] [error] [client 141.101.92.219] SoftException in Application.cpp:256: File "/home/picstore/public_html/shop/admin1385/ajax-tab.php" is writeable by group, referer: http://picstore.tn/shop/admin1385/index.php?controller=AdminLogin&token=14abda336e05072c8006141dc4ec23d2&redirect=AdminDashboard
[Wed Dec 02 22:42:01 2015] [error] [client 141.101.92.219] File does not exist: /home/picstore/public_html/500.shtml, referer: http://picstore.tn/shop/admin1385/index.php?controller=AdminLogin&token=14abda336e05072c8006141dc4ec23d2&redirect=AdminDashboard
[Wed Dec 02 22:42:01 2015] [error] [client 141.101.92.219] SoftException in Application.cpp:256: File "/home/picstore/public_html/shop/admin1385/ajax-tab.php" is writeable by group, referer: http://picstore.tn/shop/admin1385/index.php?controller=AdminLogin&token=14abda336e05072c8006141dc4ec23d2&redirect=AdminDashboard
[Wed Dec 02 22:40:42 2015] [error] [client 141.101.92.219] File does not exist: /home/picstore/public_html/500.shtml, referer: http://picstore.tn/shop/admin1385/index.php?controller=AdminLogin&token=14abda336e05072c8006141dc4ec23d2&redirect=AdminDashboard
[Wed Dec 02 22:40:42 2015] [error] [client 141.101.92.219] SoftException in Application.cpp:256: File "/home/picstore/public_html/shop/admin1385/ajax-tab.php" is writeable by group, referer: http://picstore.tn/shop/admin1385/index.php?controller=AdminLogin&token=14abda336e05072c8006141dc4ec23d2&redirect=AdminDashboard
[Wed Dec 02 22:40:24 2015] [error] [client 141.101.92.219] File does not exist: /home/picstore/public_html/500.shtml, referer: http://picstore.tn/shop/admin1385/index.php?controller=AdminLogin&token=14abda336e05072c8006141dc4ec23d2&redirect=AdminDashboard
[Wed Dec 02 22:40:24 2015] [error] [client 141.101.92.219] SoftException in Application.cpp:256: File "/home/picstore/public_html/shop/admin1385/ajax-tab.php" is writeable by group, referer: http://picstore.tn/shop/admin1385/index.php?controller=AdminLogin&token=14abda336e05072c8006141dc4ec23d2&redirect=AdminDashboard
[Wed Dec 02 22:34:41 2015] [error] [client 141.101.92.219] File does not exist: /home/picstore/public_html/500.shtml, referer: http://picstore.tn/shop/admin1385/index.php?controller=AdminLogin&token=14abda336e05072c8006141dc4ec23d2&redirect=AdminDashboard
[Wed Dec 02 22:34:41 2015] [error] [client 141.101.92.219] SoftException in Application.cpp:256: File "/home/picstore/public_html/shop/admin1385/ajax-tab.php" is writeable by group, referer: http://picstore.tn/shop/admin1385/index.php?controller=AdminLogin&token=14abda336e05072c8006141dc4ec23d2&redirect=AdminDashboard
[Wed Dec 02 22:34:21 2015] [error] [client 141.101.92.219] File does not exist: /home/picstore/public_html/500.shtml, referer: http://picstore.tn/shop/admin1385/index.php?controller=AdminLogin&token=14abda336e05072c8006141dc4ec23d2&redirect=AdminDashboard
[Wed Dec 02 22:34:21 2015] [error] [client 141.101.92.219] SoftException in Application.cpp:256: File "/home/picstore/public_html/shop/admin1385/ajax-tab.php" is writeable by group, referer: http://picstore.tn/shop/admin1385/index.php?controller=AdminLogin&token=14abda336e05072c8006141dc4ec23d2&redirect=AdminDashboard
[Wed Dec 02 22:32:05 2015] [error] [client 141.101.92.219] File does not exist: /home/picstore/public_html/500.shtml, referer: http://picstore.tn/shop/admin1385/index.php?controller=AdminLogin&token=14abda336e05072c8006141dc4ec23d2&redirect=AdminDashboard
[Wed Dec 02 22:32:05 2015] [error] [client 141.101.92.219] SoftException in Application.cpp:256: File "/home/picstore/public_html/shop/admin1385/ajax-tab.php" is writeable by group, referer: http://picstore.tn/shop/admin1385/index.php?controller=AdminLogin&token=14abda336e05072c8006141dc4ec23d2&redirect=AdminDashboard
[Wed Dec 02 22:31:55 2015] [error] [client 141.101.92.219] File does not exist: /home/picstore/public_html/500.shtml, referer: http://picstore.tn/shop/admin1385/index.php?controller=AdminLogin&token=14abda336e05072c8006141dc4ec23d2
```

But the file ajax-tab.php exists.

I will copy/past the code that calls ajax-tab.php

```
    <?php

class AdminPicstoreGenerateZipController extends ModuleAdminController {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function initContent() {

        $id = Tools::getValue('id');

        $html = '';

        if ($id) {
            $html .= '<h1>Génération de ZIP</h1>';
            $html .= '<p>génération en cour ...</p>';
            $html .= '<div id="zip_link"></div>';
            $html .= '<script type="text/javascript">
                    $.post(
                        "ajax-tab.php",
                        {
                            tab: \'AdminPicstoreGenerateZip\',
                            token: \'' . $this->token . '\',
                            ajax: \'1\',
                            action:\'GetZipLink\',
                            id:\'' . $id . '\',
                            timeout: 1000*60*30
                        }, function(a){
                            $("#zip_link").html(a);
                        });
                 </script>';
        } else {
            $html .= '<div class="bootstrap"><div class="alert alert-danger clearfix">ID introuvable</div></div>';
        }

        $this->content = $html;
        return parent::initContent();
    }

    public function ajaxProcessGetZipLink() {
        $id = Tools::getValue('id');
        if($id){
            $link = require _PS_ROOT_DIR_ . '/manager/scripts/process.php';

            die('<a href="' . $link . '">Télécharger le zip</a>');
        }else{
            die('<div class="bootstrap"><div class="alert alert-danger clearfix">ID introuvable</div></div>');
        }
    }

}
```

And here is the php code of ajax-tab.php

```
    if (!defined('_PS_ADMIN_DIR_'))
    define('_PS_ADMIN_DIR_', getcwd());

require(_PS_ADMIN_DIR_.'/../config/config.inc.php');
require(_PS_ADMIN_DIR_.'/functions.php');

// For retrocompatibility with "tab" parameter
if (!isset($_GET['controller']) && isset($_GET['tab']))
    $_GET['controller'] = strtolower($_GET['tab']);
if (!isset($_POST['controller']) && isset($_POST['tab']))
    $_POST['controller'] = strtolower($_POST['tab']);
if (!isset($_REQUEST['controller']) && isset($_REQUEST['tab']))
    $_REQUEST['controller'] = strtolower($_REQUEST['tab']);
// Retrocompatibility with 1.4
$_REQUEST['ajaxMode'] = $_POST['ajaxMode'] = $_GET['ajaxMode'] = $_REQUEST['ajax'] = $_POST['ajax'] = $_GET['ajax'] = 1;

Dispatcher::getInstance()->dispatch();
```

The module was working just fine. And I have modified any files. But since 2 days, I have an internal server error 500 with ajax-tab.php.

Do you have any idea how can I fix it ?

Thank you so much for your help

Best
Habib

Comment: look at your server's error log for details about the 500. until you've done that, there's no much point in trying to GUESS what the problem might. could be as simple as a typo in your script causing a compile error, or up to tickling a php bug causing php to crash.

Comment: You need to look in the server logs / [enable error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display)

Comment: Hello @MarcB ! Thanks for your quick reply.
I've just added a portion of my server's error log about the 500

Thanks for your help

Comment: Hey @AlexK. 
I just added the logs into the post ! Thanks ;)

Comment: I see only messages about `500.shtml` and `404.shtml` does not exists, not `ajax-tab.php`. Also, open please `config/defines.inc.php` and set `define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', true);`